# Is there a way to identify which properties have been modified though the AuditQuery?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-envers

I have an object called `Contact` and I have each property flagged as `@Audited`. Saving the changes works as expected. I can see all the data and changes in the database. What I am trying to do is access the changes. I want to get all the changes for one specific `Contact`, and I want to see which properties where changed per log. This is where I am so far.

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Contact.class, false, true);
query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(contactId));
List<Object[]> contacts = query.getResultList();
```

Right now the list of objects that comes back is the list of data that I want, however I don't know how to identify which properties were changed in each result. Is there a different/better way of doing this that would let me see which properties were modified? or does anyone else have a different idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in diff functionality in Envers, so you can either manually compare two subsequent revisions, or you can add additional columns (flags) which will hold information if the column value changed or not; see the manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-tracking-properties-changes

Comment: Yes it looks like the only way to do this is to do it manually. Thanks for the assistance